# How do I change the code to get the IoU values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've searched online on this but could not get a definitive answer on how to do it. I don't want to mess up the code. I'm running `inspect_model.ipynb` by changing the code in `model.py` from [this github repo](https://github.com/karolmajek/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/README.md). I'd like to see the IoU value of each image. What is the code modification for this ? I suppose a simple 'print' would do ? But I'm not exactly sure what and where to insert it in the code. I'm really new to this. I couldn't add the code here as there's a character limit.

Comment: The IOU between intersections? On line `479` of `model.py` IOU is calculated, you can just add a line after that with `print(iou)`.

Comment: @ZWang I tried. But it's not printed when I run the `inspect_model.ipynb`. Is there some way to call the `iou` function from within the `inspect_model.ipynb` notebook instead ?